# Expressjs to production

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I am new to expressjs, I want to deploy an expressjs app to production. Based on my googling, here's the setup on rackspace I am thinking:

1 Load balancer + 2 server + Run app with forever

My questions are:

1. What engine shall I use to run the app? nginx?
2. how many app can I run per server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you are serving static files or using any of nginx's reverse proxy features, you can use nginx.  But if not, since your servers are behind a load balancer, nginx isn't necessary at all.
2. The rule of thumb is one node.js/express.js process per core.  Have a look at [cluster](https://github.com/learnboost/cluster) to help you manage this. Make sure your load balancer knows about all the node.js processes you are running (and is not just load balancing between one IP/port pair on each server).

**Update**: Node.js now has [cluster](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) built in out of the box.

Also, if you are deploying on Ubuntu you can use upstart instead of forever if you like.

Comment: Can you explain how cluster works, I couldn't get any information from the API / Documentation.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but now node.js core has clustering built in out of the box. Check out the docs:  http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

You need nodejs installed on your machine to run nodejs. nginx is a server used for reverse proxy and a load balancer. Also you can run the app through pm2 instead of forever which will handle all the clustering and running your app in background.